# Default acceptance headers on HttpConnection, involves some risk?

Tags: java, security, httpconnection

I wonder if there is some risk in leaving the HttpConnection object in a connection with the acceptance mime types by default. That's it according to [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) to not set any header. Does that suppose any risk or future problem?

Comment: That would mostly depend on what usage you expect to make of your application. But in general, it is always better to be explicit about what you accept.

Comment: The question then is "Why is better"?

Comment: Obviously because if you don't "tell", they will need to "guess"... and some WILL guess wrong.